# Getting ggplot (python) error NameError: name 'ggplot' is not defined

Tags: python, ggplot2, plotnine

I am trying to get a graph, but I keep receiving an error saying that ggplot is not defined. i have downloaded the plotnine library

```
from plotnine import *
from plotnine.data import diamonds
import seaborn as sns
ggplot(aes(x="day"), tips) + geom_bar()


5 ggplot(aes(x="day"), tips) + geom_bar()
```

Error:

> NameError: name 'ggplot' is not defined

Comment: Please review the tags on your question - is this definitely an R question?

Comment: What does `from plotnine import ggplot, geom_bar, aes` give?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python, here is a helpful website: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-ggplot2-in-python-74ab8adec129

It seems you have to install plotnine first. Have you done this yet?

```
# Using pip
pip install plotnine         

# Using conda
conda install -c conda-forge plotnine
```